# How to use WinDbg to debug a driver

Tags: windbg

I'm following this article https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/mt269367(v=vs.85).aspx and I've gotten to the step where you run the command to start WinDbg.

`WinDbg –k net:port=50000,key=1.2.3.4`

However, when WinDbg restarts it is stuck on "Waiting to reconnect..." and it shows "Debugee not connected" at the bottom. I've tried unplugging the Ethernet cable multiple times as well as restarting the target multiple times. I can also ping the host computer from the target. Oddly, I can't ping the target from the host.

The host machine is running Windows 7 and the target machine is Windows 8.

[image: WinDbg waiting to reconnect]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So I turned off the firewall on the host and it started to work.

[image]